# How to set specific bin and width for each dataset within a Histogram3D

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d, histograms

```
data2000 = Import["D:\\db_2000cm.xls"];
..
data50 = Import["D:\\db_50cm.xls"];

Histogram3D[
{data2000[[1]], data50[[1]]}, {{"Raw", 66}, {"Raw", 40}}, "Count",
PlotRange -> {{30, 100}, {0, 2100}, {0, 800}},

Ticks -> {
{30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85, 90, 95},
{0, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100, 1200, 1300, 1400, 1500, 1600, 1700, 1800, 1900, 2000},
{0, 200, 400, 600, 800}}]
```

Produces the following plot:
[image]

Every dataset (of different number of samples) that I have available to add to this plot (right now I only have the max and min dataset which are 2000 and 50 respectively), corresponds to some value which is multiple of 50 (e.g. 2000, 1950.. down to 50). What I need is to always have a Y width of 50 for each dataset I add. With that said, the yellow distribution should start from 50 and end at 100 on y axis (or from 0 upto 50 in case this is easy), while the blue distro should start from 2000 and end to 2050 (or from 1950 and end to 2000 in case this is easy). How can I do that?

Let me also mention that the number of bins within each dataset should be 66 (i.e. from 30 up to 95 with increase of 1)

The inside of each XLS look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
nd = 40;
SeedRandom[1]
dts = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[40 + #, 10], 
     RandomInteger[{500, 1000}]] & /@ Range[nd];

Length /@ dts
```

> ```
> {918, 570, 594, 772, 823, 805, 685, 953, 967, 900, 804, 625, 616, 
> 874, 660, 793, 960, 899, 771, 1000, 800, 567, 950, 507, 789, 631, 
> 504, 588, 628, 788, 862, 561, 759, 560, 837, 898, 506, 978, 693, 971}
> ```

```
idts = MapIndexed[Thread[{#, 50 (#2[[1]])}] &, dts];
```

First 5 rows of the first data set:

```
idts[[1, ;; 5]] // Grid[#, Dividers -> All] &
```

[image]

```
Histogram3D[idts, {{"Raw", 66}, {"Raw", nd}}, "Count", 
 ImageSize -> 700, 
 ChartLegends -> {"data" <> ToString[50 #] & /@ Range[nd]}, 
 Ticks -> {Range[0, 100, 5], Range[0, 2000, 100], Automatic}]
```

[image]

To see the first 10 data sets in more detail:

```
Histogram3D[idts[[;; 10]], {{"Raw", 66}, {"Raw", 10}}, "Count", 
 ImageSize -> 700, 
 ChartLegends -> {"data" <> ToString[50 #] & /@ Range[10]}, 
 Ticks -> {Range[0, 100, 5], Range[0, 2000, 50], Automatic}]
```

[image]

To chart non-contiguous subsets of the 40 data sets, we need to change the bin specification for the y direction to `{50}` ( or to `{50,2000,50}`):

```
Histogram3D[idts[[{1, 5, 12, 20, 24}]], {{"Raw", 66}, {50}}, "Count", 
 ImageSize -> 700, 
 ChartLegends -> {"data" <> ToString[50 #] & /@ {1, 5, 12, 20, 24}}, 
 Ticks -> {Range[0, 100, 5], Range[0, 2000, 50], Automatic}]
```

[image]

To show *only two* of 40 datasets we need a trick (to work around a possible bug): add a third data set and set its style to `None`:

```
Histogram3D[idts[[{1, 40, 40}]], {{"Raw", 66}, {50}}, "Count", 
 ImageSize -> 700, 
 ChartStyle -> {{ ColorData[97] @ 1, ColorData[97] @ 40, None}}, 
 ChartLegends -> ("data" <> ToString[50 #] & /@ {1, 40}), 
 Ticks -> {Range[0, 100, 5], Range[0, 2000, 100], Automatic}]
```

[image]

The specification `{"Raw", 66}` gives 66 bins in x direction for the *combined* data set:

```
Length[HistogramList[Join @@ idts, {{"Raw", 66}, {"Raw", nd}}, "Count"][[1, 1]]] - 1
```

> ```
> 66
> ```

To get 66 bins for *each* data set, we can chart each set separately and combine the charts with `Show`:

```
Show[MapIndexed[Histogram3D[#, {{"Raw", 66}, {50}}, "Count", 
    ChartBaseStyle -> Opacity[.5], 
    ChartStyle -> ColorData[97][#2[[1]]], 
    ChartLegends -> {"data" <> ToString[50 #2[[1]]]}] &, idts[[;; 10]]], 
 PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 700, 
 Ticks -> {Range[0, 100, 5], Range[0, 2000, 50], Automatic}]
```

[image]

#### Alternative Visualizations:

**SmoothHistogram3D**

```
SmoothHistogram3D[Join @@ idts, MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}, 
  Mesh -> {{50 #, Directive[Thick, ColorData[{"Rainbow", {1, nd}}]@#]} & /@ 
     Range[nd]}, 
  PlotStyle -> None, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
  ImageSize -> Large, 
  PlotLegends -> LineLegend["Rainbow", "data" <> ToString[50 #] & /@ Range[nd]], 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 120}, Automatic, Automatic}, 
  Ticks -> {Range[0, 120, 10], Range[0, 2000, 100], Automatic}] /. 
 Line[x_] :> {Line[x], Opacity[.25], EdgeForm[], Polygon[x]}
```

[image]

**BoxWhiskerChart**

```
BoxWhiskerChart[dts, ChartStyle -> "Rainbow", 
 GridLines -> {None, Range[0, 120, 10]}, ImageSize -> 700 , 
 ChartLabels -> (Rotate[Row[{"data", 50 #}], 90 Degree] & /@ Range[nd]), 
 Joined -> True]
```

[image]

**DistributionChart**

```
DistributionChart[dts, ChartStyle -> "Rainbow", 
 GridLines -> {None, Range[0, 120, 10]}, 
 ChartElementFunction -> ChartElementDataFunction["SmoothDensity", 
   "Shape" -> "SingleSided"], 
 ImageSize -> 700 , 
 ChartLabels -> (Rotate[Row[{"data", 50 #}], 90 Degree] & /@ Range[nd])]
```

[image]

Comment: I feel I need to buy u a beer :D.
May I ask.. I have my db looking like that now: https://gouz.tinytake.com/tt/NDcxMTAwM18xNDkxNDgzMw How can I load such xls in the same data structure as yours? (There are 40 columns there and around 10k rows)

Comment: Or if it easier? How can I merge all the different tables I had before into the same data structure as idts? Same for me

Comment: if the data is in sheet 1 in file `foo.xls`  use  `dts = Import["foo.xls", {"Data", 1}]`.

Comment: Thx m8. You got some good karma coming from some random side of this world :D. It worked

Answer (score 1):

It is the 21st century and one should jettison the lumpy histogram for continuous data.
One can easily use `SmoothHistogram`.  This also gets you appropriate "bin widths" for each set of data.

Using the data generated by @kglr one can create the smooth histograms and collect the data to plot the resulting curves:

```
sh = SmoothHistogram[#, Automatic, "PDF", PlotRange -> {{0, 120}, {0, 0.05}}] & /@ dts;
curves = Table[Flatten[{i, #}] & /@ Flatten[List @@ Cases[sh[[i]], _Line, Infinity][[1]], 1], 
  {i, nd}];
```

Now turn those curves into polygons and lines:

```
p = Table[Polygon @@ {curves[[i]]}, {i, nd}];
lines = Table[Line @@ {curves[[i]]}, {i, nd}];
```

Finally draw all of the smoothed histograms in a 3D plot:

```
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[Thick], p, Black, lines}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 3/4},
  Axes -> True, AxesEdge -> {{1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}}]
```

[image: Collection of 2D histograms]